# InfoWindow & GeoCoder

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I have an issue with getting longitude and latitude values geocoded and then display the relevant address in an info window.  I have tried multiple ways without success, however I must admit that I am not so familiar with javascript.  I am continuously getting back as value :  "undefined".

Here is a snippet of my code showing the main components:

`var position = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address;`

```
if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': position }, function (results, status) {       
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            address = (results[0].formatted_address);
       } else { 
            address = (position.coords.latitude + ', ' +  position.coords.longitude);
       }           
    }); 
}

var info = 
          ('<span class="txt_bld">Location:</span> '         + address                      + '<br />' +
          '<span class="txt_bld">Accuracy:</span> '          + position.coords.accuracy     + '<br />' +
          '<span class="txt_bld">Time:</span> '              +  position.timestamp);
```

Can anyone tell me how I can translate the lat/lng in position to an address in order to show them in my infowindow?

**EDIT**

Updated Code:

    `var position = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var address;`

```
if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': position }, function (results, status) {       
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            address == (results[0].formatted_address);
       } else { 
            address == (position.coords.latitude + ', ' +  position.coords.longitude);
       }    
       var info = 
          ('<span class="txt_bld">Location:</span> '         + address                      + '<br />' +
          '<span class="txt_bld">Accuracy:</span> '          + position.coords.accuracy     + '<br />' +
          '<span class="txt_bld">Time:</span> '              + position.timestamp); 

        if(!infowindow){
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: info
            });
        }else{
            infowindow.setContent(info);
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);    
          setTimeout(function () { 
            infowindow.close(); 
          }, 5000);
        });            
    }); 
}
```

`if(!marker){
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: this.map,
        icon: markericon,
        draggable:false
        });
    }else{
        marker.setPosition(point);

    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geocoder is asynchronous.  You need to use the data  it returns in the callback function.  Something like this (not tested):

```
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude); 
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var address;

if (geocoder) {
  geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': position }, function (results, status) {       
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        address = (results[0].formatted_address);
   } else { 
        address = (position.coords.latitude + ', ' +  position.coords.longitude);
   }           
   var info = 
      ('<span class="txt_bld">Location:</span> '         + address
       + '<br />' +
      '<span class="txt_bld">Accuracy:</span> '          + position.coords.accuracy
      + '<br />' +
      '<span class="txt_bld">Time:</span> '              +  position.timestamp);
    infowindow.setContent(info);
    infowindow.setPosition(position);
    infowindow.open(map);
  }); 
}
```

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_revGeocodeIW.html)

Comment: I have updated the code in my question.  That is what I came up to, however I am still getting the Location as Undefined

Comment: Where is "Location" undefined?  Where is marker defined?  Can you provide a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem?

Comment: the marker is defined after the if(geocoder).  I updated the code above.

In the html when I click on the marker and get the infowindow, I get the following:

Location: undefined
Accuracy: 35
Etc..

Comment: Your code is different from mine.  "==" is not the same as "=".

Answer (score 0):

We are using geocoder to get Lat long by address, as we don't have Lat long so we need to find Lat long via geocoder. In case if we have Lat long coordinates then we can use direct

```js
 var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i][0]
            });
```